# In search of a a random "sentence" or "line" generator based on predefined "sets" of words in excel

Tags: excel, random, set, generator

Not sure where I am supposed to ask this question, (if this is the wrong place, please help me locate the correct location).

I am in search of a a random "sentance" or "line" generator based on predefined "sets" of words. For example:

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Set 1

---

1. Hey John,
2. Hi Mary,
3. How are you, Bob,

Set 2

---

1. Hope you are doing well.
2. Haven't seen you in awhile.
3. How's your son doing?

Set 3

---

1. My number changed. Here's my new one.
2. I'm late for something, gotta run
3. What's your number again? Can I call you later?

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Random Line from Set 1 + Random Line from Set 2 + Random Line from Set 3 = Random Mashup of All Sets

I.E. - Hi Mary, How's your Son Doing? My number changed. Here's my new one.

Does something like this exist in Excel?

Comment: Perhaps a [formal grammar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_grammar) would help.

Comment: I've voted to close this as far too broad. At the very least, we need to know what language you want this in. I know that I can personally write it for you in bash, C, C++, C#, javascript, python, or even Visual Basic.  When the question leaves me that many choices in how to answer, it's too broad.  You have 3 different arrays or lists.  All you want is a simple program that randomly chooses one element from each array/list, and concatenates the results into a string.  Very possible to do.  It helps us to see what you've tried, because it tells us what language, and what you know of it.

Comment: Also, without determining what language you want, most people won't notice this post.  Change your tags to at least have a language, and then, for good or ill, more people will see your question.

Comment: Sorry for the left out information, how would I accomplish something like this in Excel?

Answer (score 0):

Solution 1: If you want a single composite result

1. Iterate through the sets
2. For each set, generate a random integer in the range of the set count
3. Print or use the set element corresponding to the generated value

Solution 2: If you want multiple unique results

1. Shuffle each of the sets (builtin shuffle or [Fisher-Yates/Knuth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle)
   shuffle, depending on your language's library)
2. Initialize an index to the lowest/first value used by your language
   to index sets
3. Iterate through the sets and print or use the set element with the current
   index
4. Increment the index and go to step 3 if indices remain

---

Since you've altered your question to be specific to Excel:

1. Put your three sets in three separate sheets.
2. Add a column of random numbers to each sheet.
3. Sort the sheets by the random number columns, which will shuffle
   your sets.
4. Assemble your results by concatenating the set entries from each
   sheet that share the same row.